# How to know which all users have a account?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, user-accounts

In my PC I have the following directory for the users:

```
C:\Users
```

And my account is:

```
C:\Users\rkp10
```

So how do I know which all users (such as in this case "rkp10") , have been created in my computer?
I am using python but have no Idea how to know.

Comment: have you tried go over the users file as admin? pretty sure you can see all the users

Comment: You want a list of all the user accounts on your system?

Comment: @StanVanhoorn, yes.

Comment: "net user" from cmd

Comment: `net user` only works for local users! Domain Users are not shown on my laptop with `net user`!

Answer (score 0):

You can enumerate the users on a machine by calling [`NetUserEnum`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370652) via PyWin32's [`win32net.NetUserEnum`](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.7/pywin32/win32net__NetUserEnum_meth.html). For example:

```
import win32net
import win32netcon

def listusers(server=None):
    level = 0
    filter = win32netcon.FILTER_NORMAL_ACCOUNT
    resume_handle = 0
    user_list = []
    while True:
        result = win32net.NetUserEnum(server, level, filter, resume_handle)
        user_list += [user['name'] for user in result[0]]
        resume_handle = result[2]
        if not resume_handle:
            break
    user_list.sort()
    return user_list
```